# Redirect with Javascript and set request attribute

Tags: javascript, redirect, request

I'm trying to perform a redirect to a different page in Javascript AND also set a request attribute for that redirect.

I don't want a request parameter like so:

```
window.location.href="www.somesite.com/id=123"
```

because I don't want the user to see the value being passed in the address bar.

One way I see is to have a form in the page with a hidden field and to set the field and submit the form from Javascript.

Is there some easier way?

Thanks...

Comment: There is no `POST` redirect in JavaScript. You'll need to to an (a)synchronous request with an XMLHttpRequest object or something similar, like jQuery's `.ajax` method, however this won't result in a redirect. Just use a `<form>`.

Comment: you can set a cookie and redirect after that

Comment: Thank you both for the tips :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Form and post it via window.onload.

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="/someurl">
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="X" />
</form>

<script>
window.onload=function(){ document.getElementById('myForm').submit(); }
```

and you're done.

Comment: @alphamale: **i am sorry to disagree, but you positively can post data using javascript.** the above example works perfectly as expected.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some other way to do it, but submitting a POST-method form in Javascript (as in your example) is what I eventually did. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can not post data using javascript.**.. You can use `ajax` to do that. or you can use something like this in your `javascript` to achieve what you are trying to:

```
var post_url = 'http://www.somesite.com/id=123';
var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="get">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" />' +
'</form>');
$(form).submit();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks :) this is also an interesting tip. As Lupo suggested, it is possible to use the POST method in such case. I found a little more detailed description of this approach here: http://forrst.com/posts/JavaScript_redirect_with_POST_params-u0M (posting link, perhaps it'll be helpful to someone.